# E: Unable to locate package python-image

Tags: python, python-2.7

I use This command for installation but I face this error:

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-opencv python-picamera python-image python-pyexiv2

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree    

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package python-image
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/156484/how-do-i-install-python-imaging-library-pil - relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your package probably already exist.

You can try:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install python-image
```

it should fix.

In case you do not have your repo well set-up, you might need to add the repo `universe`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Otherwise you have a detailed solution there:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt